# How do I do an http request upon successful Inno Setup install, for tracking purposes?

Tags: postback, inno-setup

When my program successfully installs via Inno Setup, how do I run a URL in the background? I want to just load a tracking pixel (or a postback) which says that my program was installed.

I'm aware than in the [Run] section, I can run a .url file with the flag "runhidden", but as far as I know that won't do what I need it to. Am I wrong about that, or are there better option?

Thank you.

Comment: Doing that won't get past Windows Firewall, for one, and is a violation of user privacy for another. You shouldn't be trying to do this at all, IMO; it's the way malware/spyware work.

Comment: there are tons of installers that do this, and it's the only way for companies to track their softwares' installation. I don't see why this is a problem. Plus, the Inno Setup installation is run as administrator, so it should be fine, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Name one current one. I know of dozens that open a new browser instance after a successful install, but I don't know of any that try and do it behind the user's back. Running as admin during install doesn't magically open the firewall, and doesn't automatically allow malware/spyware to work.

Comment: Alright, I'll probably launch a browser window. I can just do that via [Run] and run a .url file, correct?

Comment: Yes, that should work (and it's much less invasive). :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no TCP/IP related Support Functions, defined by default.
You could build this functionality into a DLL and [call it from you Install Script](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptdll.htm).

This is done installation's where Activation is required to make the program work.

However, I would just launch a browser window using the `[Run]` section that contains "Getting Started" information.    You can then track hits to that page.

Comment: Are there any risks of pop-up blockers blocking this page if I just use the Run section? This method seems a bit flawed since the user can also close the browser before the page loads.

Comment: Hardware and Software Firewalls, Proxies, popup blockers, user actions could prevent this type of activity.   Phoning home is never 100% It's like what spyware would do.   Hence my recommendation, it gives you a very close count of how many of installed your application, and gives them value.   Something that is far less Spyware worthy.

Comment: If you want installation counts,  Require activation of your software.